# wildcard function output in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I was trying to get the path of `ls` just to test using makefile. I did the following:

```
paths = $(addsuffix /ls,$(subst :, ,$(PATH)))
repath = $(wildcard $(paths))
result = $(firstword $(repath))

all : ; @echo "the repath contains $(repath)"
    @echo "the  result contains $(result)"
```

The wildcard function returns only `/bin/ls`. That's exactly what I want but I'm stuck in understanding wildcard output.

My `PATH` contains the following colon-delimited directories (split here on multiple lines for legibility):

```
/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin
/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/home/betatest/bin
```

And after the suffix addition it will be:

```
/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin/ls
/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin/ls
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/ls
/usr/local/bin/ls
/usr/bin/ls
/bin/ls
/usr/local/sbin/ls
/usr/sbin/ls
/sbin/ls
/home/betatest/bin/ls
```

So why is the wildcard function's output only `/bin/ls`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wildcard` function gives a list of things that exist and match the given pattern. In this case the given pattern is

```
/usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin/ls /usr/local/cuda-6.0/bin/ls /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/ls /usr/local/bin/ls /usr/bin/ls /bin/ls /usr/local/sbin/ls /usr/sbin/ls /sbin/ls /home/betatest/bin/ls
```

I suspect that the only one of those files that actually exists is `/bin/ls`, so that is the result.

Comment: Not paths but repath contains the value that shows that ls (ls command binary) is available on the system. but I want to know how wildcard function gives it.

Comment: This answer explains that quite clearly, doesn't it?

Comment: @tripleee  Sir! I am interested in like how the wildcard function work. what I perceived is ; It does similar like in shell script:<br/> ls <pattern> | grep <filename> <br/> Am I getting right or getaway from track.

Comment: So if you have a file called `foo` but no files named `bar` or `baz`, then `$(wildcard foo bar baz)` will return `foo`.

Comment: My question is how wildcard function finds the files lists from pattern name like `*.c or /usr/bin or /usr/local/gcc` is it performing similar like `ls` does or it uses similar like `find`  or some other way to locate or find the files.

Comment: `ls` does no wildcard expansion on its own.  If you do `ls *.txt` then the shell will expand `*.txt` and pass the list to `ls`.  `find` can do wildcard expansion of its own, but I would simply say that the shell and Make do a similar job in this respect.

Comment: Just to be clear, `wildcard` is not like `find`: `find` looks through directories recursively.  `wildcard` just expands the given globbing pattern and doesn't search recursively.